# Возможна beta-редукция?

Tags: haskell

Всем привет! Тренируюсь с лямбда-исчислением и задаюсь вопросом, можно ли в таком примере провести такую \beta-редукцию?

```
x(xz)(\x'z'.x'(xz)z')(xz) -> x x z x x z z
```

Comment: Редуцирование здесь невозможно, т.к. применение влево ассоциативно, и поэтому тут ничего ни к чему не применяется